# Yii relation 3 table with extra fields

Tags: php, yii

Hi I am new in yii development. I have 3 tables. Tables A,AB,B where A is one table, AB is the intermediate table which contains the FK of table A and B and B is another table. 
I have in my model the relations functions.

```
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        "AB"=>array(self::MANY_MANY,"AB(my model)","AB(A_id,B_id)"),
    );
}
```

And this workes fine, but now i want to put an order field in the table AB which will be used as and ordering field named ord, in order to have the relation AB sorted in my predefined way.

Has anyone tried something like that or has any proposals on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. The easiest way to do it is using CDbCriteria (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria), with which you can create complex sql queries.

I don't know the exact situation, but your solution will be something like

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(); 
$criteria->select = "x"; 
$criteria->alias = "tableA"; // creates a "...From table_A AS tableA..."
$criteria->join = "LEFT JOIN A_B AS tableAB ON tableA.A=tableAB.A"; 
$models = YourModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

The web is full with stuff like this, simply google mysql join or yii join.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response but the ordeing field must be in the relationship (AB table) because the order that i want is the order in which the row from table A is inserted in table B.